# Filtering view without filtering data using table calculation functions doesnt work for running sums

Tags: tableau-api, cumulative-sum

You can see my sample tableau workbook [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ivRpzOXzLazwAexe8OaE_oe6TmtJPTRM/view?usp=sharing).

If you create a running total viz and then hide some columns, the underlying data for the sheet does not change and your viz is still valid. However, if you try achieving the same thing using a filter based on table calculation functions like `lookup()`, it messes up the visualization by skipping some values. Most likely a bug in tableau but would really want to know if there is a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the `WINDOW` functions instead. Such as: `WINDOW_MAX(MAX(YEAR([Joining Date])))` computed on `Gender`. `LOOKUP` will not work as it is trying to look up the value for each month for each gender. Therefore if there was no turnover for a gender in the month, there is nothing to lookup and you get those blanks (aka #Missing). Using something like `WINDOW_MAX` computed on `Gender`, will just look at the whole month and whatever data is available it will take the MAX of and therefore won't cause this problem.